# C99 style variable-length array function signature in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c99

In C99 we can write function signatures like so:

```
void func(int dim1, int dim2, float A[dim1 * dim2]);
```

`dim1` and `dim2` are runtime parameters. This is kind of nice, since any user of such a function immediately has an idea about the dimensionality of `A` and can thus infer further information without reading comments/documentation. This is especially true if `dim1` and `dim2` are parameters with semantics beyond what is shown here.

Is it possible to write an interface in C++ that gives a hint about the dimensionality and size of a vector/tensor that a function expects? Dimensionality can probably be encoded as a template argument (something I don't like in particular but that is another topic) but size? Any ideas?

**Update:**

I have to make it clearer, I guess. A C++ function would look like so:

```
void func(int dim1, int dim2, std::vector<float> A);
```

and one of the two dimensions can even be omitted (since it it is `A.size()/dim`). But the signature does not tell the user anything about the size of the vector that the function expects. Of course I can `assert(A.size() == dim1*dim2);` and things like that. That is not what I am asking about. I'm asking how to make the interface more informative.

**Update 2:**

So I'm pretty sure what I want is this:

```
typedef int dim1; 
typedef int dim2; 
void func(Matrix<dim1, dim2> A);
```

As was mentioned in the answer, the information must be in the type - of course.

Comment: Why not use a type that tells you its size/dimensions? There's no need for a "hint" then.

Comment: @MikeSeymour as I said, dim1 and dim2 are runtime parameters. They are not known at compile time and can not be encoded in the type.

Comment: @Sebastian, No need to encode it in the type then. For example, `std::vector` has a runtime size. You can still retrieve it and enforce it just fine.

Comment: @Sebastian: Sorry, I should have been more verbose. I meant "use a type with an interface that can be used to determine the size/dimensions of a given instance, along the lines of the `size()` member of standard containers", not necessarily a type that statically encodes the information.

Comment: `float A[X]` in parameters in C is literally the same as `float* A`. I'll bet this also holds in C++ (for compat reasons). You could just document the type elsewhere *OR* create a macro `#define PARAM_DIM(x)` that expands to nothing: `float A[PARAM_DIM(x * y)]` -> `float A[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, you'd do `void func(Matrix const& A)`. The dimensions would be encoded in the matrix itself, so there'd be no need to pass them separately. This both ensures the accuracy of the dimensions, and simplifies the calling idiom.

Comment: I agree with your of course, but that is not what I am asking I guess. A function signature `void mix(int apples, int oranges, float mixture[apples * oranges]);` conveys more information than `void mix(Matrix<float> mixture);` right?

Comment: @Sebastian, A matrix inherently has two dimensions of known size and a total size of those multiplied together. Extra parameters for those dimensions and the multiplication are both redundant.

Comment: @chris I know all this. I figured out what I want now, though. I want to name the dimensions of the Matrix.

Comment: @Sebastian: Indeed, the function signature itself would convey less information. The information would come from the parameter type instead. This is generally regarded as a good thing.

Comment: You're all right. I am pretty sure I want this: `typedef int dim1; typedef int dim2; void func(Matrix<dim1, dim2> A);` I completely agree @MikeSeymour - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::array`:

```
void func(std::array<int, /* dimension */> &arr);
```

Comment: `dim1` and `dim2` are runtime parameters, std::array is a container for constant (as in compiletime) size arrays.